# Split numbers and letters in an Alphanumeric String

Tags: java, string, split

I need to split an Alphanumeric String and split the alphabets and numbers. For example, if I have a string like: "Room 502", I need to get the number 502 as a separate string to "Room". Could someone please help me with this?

I know it's probably something so simple, but all the examples I have seen don't seem to do what I need.

Comment: ya, you can use `split`

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Does the string necessarily have the form "<word> <number>" ?

Comment: You need to be more specific as well. For example are you looking to split the string around spaces, or are you looking to scan it and pull out all numbers, or what?

Comment: A straightforward solution would be to iterate over the characters in the String and check each character if it's a number or an alphabet and then separate them out.  You can think of any optimisations later.  Please post some code of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

For this example, you could just split on the space character, since the string is literally `Room 502` and you want `Room` and `502`, you could just do:

```
String example = "Room 502";
String[] components = string.split(" ");
```

If what you are trying to split is a bit more complex, for example `Room502isnice` as suggested in the comments, we have to use something called a regular expression, or regex.

The following regular expression would split the string `Room502isnice` into `Room`, `502` and `isnice`:

```
([A-z]+)|(\d+)
```

I'm not an expert in Java so I'm not 100% sure how it would be applied in Java.

See this regexr example:
http://regexr.com/399uu

Comment: What if the String is "Room502isnice".  Your solution won't work.  I believe it needs to be generic enough to deal with any order of alphabets and numbers.

Comment: Don't answer questions which are of *bad quality*. You don't know what the OP wants, yet you answer it?

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. My apologies for not being more precise with my question. I have barcodes that I need to create and scan. Instead of just adding a barcode that reads "1" or "502", I wanted it to read "Room 1", but only get the value "1".

Comment: `[A-z]` represents characters in Unicode range between `A` and `z` but between these characters beside alphabetic there are also `[` ``\`` `]` `^` `_` `\`` so it is better to use `[A-Za-z]` to avoid these additional characters.